# Integrate TomCat and Node server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, jsp, tomcat

I have an existing JSP, Anuglar 1 application deployed on TomCat server during development. I would like to migrate JSP pages to Anuglar 2+ one by one.

I am using Node / NPM for Angular 2+ migrated pages. Is it possible to set proxy in TomCat server such that whenever an angular 2+ page is requested, it would redirect the user to Node server to serve Angular 2+ pages?

I understand Angular 2+ page can be directly copied to TomCat server but it would require additional compilation step to convert them to static JS pages. I would like to serve them directly from Node server for faster development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, you really shouldn't serve `angular` pages dynamically. Even if you do serve them from `node`, serve compiled static pages instead of `ng serve` - for security, performance and other reasons.

With that said, sure you can do this. This depends a little on your setup, but what it comes down to is that you need to proxy all the `angular` pages to `node` server. This has not a lot to do with Angular itself.

So, the easiest way to do this is to tell `Apache` (or `nginx` or whoever is in front of your Tomcat) to proxy all 404s to the `node` server. Then `node` will render `angular` site, and this in turn will match the url and render the given page, or if not found, render it's own version of 404.

Alternatively, give your `apache` or whatever, a specific list of URLs (that are already ported) to pass through to `node` server.

If you don't use `Apache`, but are serving things out of `Tomcat` directly (you shouldn't), you can use something like [this](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I think it should work. For now, I managed to do this by creating a proxy on Node server.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat itself does not have a reverse proxy built into it.  However, you can accomplish what you're asking if you implement the proxying in your application (i.e. as a servlet or filter).

To do this you could use existing software, like [Netflix Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) or if you're using Spring then [Spring Cloud Netflix](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_router_and_filter_zuul).  Zuul has a lot more features than just a reverse proxy, but it something that would work for both production and development.

The [Tomcat Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/ServletProxy) has more options, and I'm sure you can turn up even more by searching for something like "reverse proxy servlet".  Just be careful if this is something you're going to put in production, and test both performance and security of the solution you end up using.

You could also put a traditional reverse proxy like Apache HTTPD or Nginx in front of Tomcat & your node server, but that's one more thing to run on your developer machine.

Hope that helps!